# What's the difference between Children and GetChildren in Sitecore? (v8.1)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

So looking through the Sitecore code I notice multiple ways to get the children of an `Item`.

```cs
// Summary:
//     Gets the children.
public ChildList GetChildren();
```

and

```cs
// Summary:
//     Gets a list of child items.
public ChildList Children { get; }
```

Any thoughts on the differences between them?

Also do not confuse with the overloaded method:

```cs
GetChildren(ChildListOptions options)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Item.GetChildren() allows parameters to alter functionality. This flexibility is why .GetChildren() is preferred over .Children for retrieving a ChildList collection of children items.

For example, to ignore any security applied on those items, use: item.GetChildren(Sitecore.Collections.ChildListOptions.IgnoreSecurity)

Above is the code for these three methods/property

```
public ChildList GetChildren()
{
  return this.GetChildren(ChildListOptions.None);
}

public ChildList GetChildren(ChildListOptions options)
{
  return Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull<ChildList>(ItemManager.GetChildren(this, (options & ChildListOptions.IgnoreSecurity) != ChildListOptions.None ? SecurityCheck.Disable : SecurityCheck.Enable, options));
}

public ChildList Children
{
  get
  {
    return new ChildList(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code? Sitecore is closed source.

Comment: I decompile dll using Dot Peek

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between them

They both call `ItemManager.GetChildren();` in behind with `ChildListOptions.None` options.

And they both return `ChildList` object in return.

Comment: Then why have both? Just to make intellisense happy?

Comment: Haha that's a question for Sitecore, not for me :)